# JSONArray constructor issue

Tags: java, json

```
{"balance":1000.21,"is_vip":true,"num":100,"name":"foo"}
```

This is my json string. I want to iterate each element and get my output as

```
1000
true
100
foo
```

I tried creating JSONArray with the following syntax

```
  JSONArray jsonarr = new JSONArray(myString);
```

But the error thrown is

```
 "The constructor JSONArray(String) is undefined"
```

So what can be the possible solution this?

Comment: Which programming language are you using ?

Comment: using JAVA as the language

Comment: The JSON you provided has no array in it. What you have is a JSON **object** with various name value pairs inside of it. If you don't understand JSON syntax you should do your research before trying to write logic to parse it. http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Comment: Which library are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `JSONObject` class instead:

```
JSONObject jso = new JSONObject(yourJsonString);

// values
for(int i = 0; i<jso.names().length(); i++){
    System.out.println( jso.get( jso.names().getString(i) ) );
}
```