# value br of type java.lang.string cannot be converted to jsonarray

Tags: java, android, sql, json

I am trying to register users in the SQL database through Android using java. But before registering, I want to check if the user is already registered or not.

This is my code to check. But is returning error: value br of type java.lang.string cannot be converted to jsonarray. The response from server is not in the form of JsonArray.

Please help me to solve it.

> **registerActivity.java**

```java
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, IsUserExist, new Response.Listener < String > () {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);

                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Number Already Registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                if (jsonObject.getString("status").equals("true")) {
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Number Already Registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else {
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "HELLO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    register(mobilenumber);
                    //   PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                    //          mobilenumber,
                    //        120,
                    //      java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                    //    getActivity(),
                    //  mCallbacks);
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            pDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error Please tyr again" + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}) {
    @Override
    protected Map < String, String > getParams() {
        Map < String, String > params = new HashMap < String, String > ();
        params.put("mobile", mobilenumber);
        return params;
    }

};

Volley.newRequestQueue(RegisterActivity.this).add(stringRequest);
```

> **isUserExists.php**

```php
$mobile = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["mobile"]);

$query= "SELECT * from users WHERE mobile =$mobile";

$rows = mysqli_query($con,$query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($rows) < 0){
    $response[] = array(
        "status"    => "true",
        "message"   => "User already exists"
    );

    return response($response);
}else{
    $response[] = array(
        "status"    => "false",
        "message"   => "User donot exists");

    return response($response);
}
```

Comment: If you got `String` as response you cannot do `JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);` since response is only String. You can make JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response); Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47142657/jsonarray-constructor-issue

Comment: Could you post the content of response? Because it seems that the response is not in valid JSON format.

Comment: how can i view the content of the response and post it here ? kindly guide me a little bit.